# How do you uncompress duplicity difftar to usable files?

Tags: compression, cygwin, duplicity

I made a backup on a linux machine using dejadup or duplicity. All the files are .difftar files. I have been trying to decompress them on Windows 10 and also the old linux machine but nothing really works. I have tried simply unzipping with 7-Zip and PeaZip which gives the image pasted done with PeaZip.  I'm going bonkers and if anyone has a method to decompress these files I'd surely appreciate it. I have tried duplicati, Hasleo, Aomei, installed cygwin with dejadup and duplicity (which looked promising but threw so many errors it's not funny). Can anyone help with this. I do have the manifest to help look for what I want, but it's 40 gigs of material.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0zaY.png)

I have tried duplicati, Hasleo, Aomei, installed cygwin with dejadup and duplicity (which looked promising but threw so many errors it's not funny). Can anyone help with this? Either a program or app to use or instructions. I do have the manifest to help look for what I want, but it's 40 gigs of material.

I also made a live CD of elementary OS to see if that would help to access a copy of the duplicity difftars on the windows machine, and still nothing and more of the same. The docs on duplicity and PeaZip have been very unhelpful and light.

Comment: `which looked promising but threw so many errors it's not funny` is not very useful to help you; you need to be specific and with details. In addition your request is more for PowerUser than for StackOverflow as it is NOT a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

there was a documentation page, which since has vanished but is archived here

https://web.archive.org/web/20150419122415/https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase

if you need more help i suggest you join the duplicity mailing list and ask there or open a ticket on https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues .